# How to make new connect monitor primaryScreen

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program, which can identify all monitors ,but if we get determined monitor, we must make its primaryScreen(), but I don t know how it doing, in advance Thanks

Comment: You should provide more context around your question, without looking at the code chances are no one can tell what it is doing. If your only problem is understanding the code then have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1):

`primaryScreen()` is a value Qt reads from the operating system.

You need to change your primary screen in your OS display settings. Qt can't do that out of the box.

Comment: I know, that primaryScreen() return number of monitor which primary and class QDesktopWidget also has signal screenCountChanged(), but I don t know how I can make new monitor primaryScreen

Comment: For Win10: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3871-change-main-display-windows-10-a.html

Comment: As martin has stated above you can't make an aux screen the primary screen, but that isn't really relevant to Qt. You can have a full screen application and based on user selection, cast a specifies screen over a desired region. It really depends on what your trying to do. Depending on your OS you may be able to use c++ api's to change system properties, but that's the best I can tell you.